# Info about parameters and rendered partials missing from Rails development log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is how a normal Rails 3.2 log file entry looks like:

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-05 14:36:43 +0200  
Processing by Admin::PagesController#show as HTML  
  Parameters: {"id"=>"admin/dashboard"}  
  Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT 'posts'.* FROM 'posts' WHERE 'posts'.'riddle' = 1 AND 'posts'.'solved_at' <= '2013-08-05 12:36:43' ORDER BY comments_count DESC LIMIT 1  
  [...]  
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 'comments'.* FROM 'comments' WHERE 'comments'.'post_id' = 74 ORDER BY 'comments'.'id' DESC LIMIT 1  
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'posts' WHERE 'posts'.'riddle' = 1  
  Rendered admin/dashboard.html.haml within layouts/admin (109.1ms)  
  Rendered shared/admin/_header.html.haml (3.8ms)
```

**The problem: in one of my apps, the leading `Processing ...` and `Parameters: ...` and trailing `Rendered ...` lines are missing and I can't for the life of me figure out why!**

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-05 14:36:43 +0200  
  Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT 'posts'.* FROM 'posts' WHERE 'posts'.'riddle' = 1 AND 'posts'.'solved_at' <= '2013-08-05 12:36:43' ORDER BY comments_count DESC LIMIT 1  
  [...]  
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 'comments'.* FROM 'comments' WHERE 'comments'.'post_id' = 74 ORDER BY 'comments'.'id' DESC LIMIT 1  
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'posts' WHERE 'posts'.'riddle' = 1
```

The app is too big and includes too many gems to post relevant parts here, but I tried removing gems in development, verified that the log level is set to `:debug`, the logger is the standard one etc.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the `Logger` used by `ActionController::Base` is the same as the one used for the rest of the app. In the rails console, `ActionController::Base.logger == Rails.logger` should be `true`.

If it is `false`, then the app is somewhere setting up a specific `Logger` for `ActionController::Base` using something like `ActionController::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new('log/controllers.log'))`

Comment: Oh jeez, of course, that was it... I had configured the `Rails.logger` to autorotate in `development.rb` like this: `config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 10, 10.megabytes)` (which seems to be deprecated in Rails >= 3.1. Removing that line made everything appear in the log again. Thanks! (you'll get your bounty, I must wait another 18 hours before awarding it...)

Comment: You've been bountied.